# How to add a Proxy Respository to the Public Repositories group

Tags: nexus

In my local Nexus install I have a proxy configured that points to a Hosted repository on another server.

The prosy looks like it is configured correctly.

However the problem is this Proxy Repository doesn't appear in the list of available repositores so I cannot add it to the Public Repositories group??

Answer (score 1):

You probably just had to refresh the list of repositories in the user interface by either pressing the "Refresh" button or doing a browser based refresh (e.g. F5) to reload the list with the latest added repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely it appeared over-night.

It maybe that the index or the discovery of the Proxy Repo didn't complete and it doesn't appear until it finishes.